# How to write an open interval in $R^{2}$ or higher

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation, real-numbers

I want to check my understanding on writing intervals in terms of set notation in higher dimensions. What I am meaning is for example $(a,b) \subset \mathbb{R} = \{x \in \mathbb{R}: a<x<b \}$

So would it be the following as subsets of higher dimensions of $\mathbb{R}$?

$(a,b) \subset \mathbb{R}^{2} = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^{2}: a<x<b, y=0\}$

$(a,b) \subset \mathbb{R}^{3} = \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^{3}: a<x<b, y =0, z=0\}$

I wasn't sure if the final example should be

$\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^{3}: a<x<b, a<y<b, z=0\}$. (just by pattern matching the $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ case).

Comment: Where are you seeing the notation $(a,b)\subset \Bbb{R}^2$? In my experience, such things are usually not written because, as you have noticed, it's not so clear what they should mean. (For instance, why favor the $x$-variable here? Why favor the $x$-axis over, say, $y=1$?)

Comment: @EricNathanStucky It was in Baby Rudin, so it just got me thinking what the correct way to write it was.

Comment: I don't know what you have in mind but we usually don't care about intervals like that in higher dimensions. Intervals represent open balls in $\mathbb R$ so we usually look at them as a special case of that.

Comment: @EricNathanStucky Example 2.21 it considers the segment $(a,b)$ as a subset of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$. It appears to be done to demonstrate that $(a,b)$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$ but it is not open in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the cartesian product.
$$(a,b)\times\left\{0\right\}=\left\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:a<x<b,y=0\right\}$$
$$(a,b)\times\left\{0\right\}\times\left\{0\right\}=(a,b)\times\left\{0\right\}^2=\left\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:a<x<b,y=0,z=0\right\}$$

Generally,
$$\prod_{i=1}^d(a_i,b_i)=\left\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^d:a_i<x_i<b_i\;\;\forall i\leq d\right\}$$

Answer (score 2):

As discussed in the comments, this notation comes from Example 2.21(g) of Rudin's *Principles of Mathematical Analysis*, which states:

> ... the segment $(a,b)$ is not open if we regard it as a subset of $R^2$, but it is an open subset of $R^1$.

In my experience, it is rather nonstandard to write $(a,b)\subset\Bbb{R}^2$ without further comment because it is ambiguous; your two tries at a definition in $\Bbb{R}^3$ capture some of that ambiguity clearly. However, in this context, I agree that your formalization $(a,b) \subset \mathbb{R}^{2} = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^{2}: a<x<b, y=0\}$ is what was intended.

Given this context, I also think your first try at the $\Bbb{R}^3$ definition is more likely than your second one. This is because seems likely that when Rudin is writes $(a,b)$, he is intending it to be, at minimum, homeomorphic to the usual interval. This is a property that your first try in $\Bbb{R}^3$ satisfies, but your second one does not.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't clear to me where this intuition of yours is supposed to come from. In some contexts it is customary to indicate by (open) [interval in $\Bbb R^n$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_(mathematics)#Multi-dimensional_intervals) a cartesian product of (open) intervals. I would say that there isn't really a universally accepted notion of interval in $\Bbb R^n$, but the argument can be made that, by lack of competitors, this one is the standard.

Answer (score 0):

basically the idea is to multiplie a standart ideal times the zero others coordinates, in that order of ideas  an interval on the x's axis on $\mathbb{R} ^n$ will be
$$(a, b)\times \{0\}\dots \times\{0\}$$
and it is equal to
$$\{(x_1,\dots, x_n) | a<x_1<b, x_2=\dots x_n=0\}.$$